# How to use Spring as email storage

Tags: java, email

Pls can anyone tell me how to use spring as temporarily email storage? Basically i need to store email temporarily in memory if it couldn't connect to email server(reason like network error).then application should try to reconnect to  the mail server.once it connect it should send email in memory.

Answer (score 3):

Spring doesn't really have a solution for this use case.

There are a couple of options:

1. Get an SMTP server setup on the localhost such that it will relay the message to the central instance. This removes the network connection between your application and the mail server hence should hopefully make the chance of not reaching it very small.
2. Store the message in the DB, not ideal as if there is a network issue that prevented access to the mail server, there could easly be a network issue that effects db access. Also you will have to create some sort of retry process to resend the message every x minutes
3. Post the message to a local persistant JMS Queue then have a message driven bean (or spring messaging container) remove the message and post it to the mail server

In my personal experience option 1. ussually gets me close enough to the level of service I need, but you will have to evalutate your own requirements.

I've actually seen option 3 implemented in a production system badly with a remote JMS broker. The important feature is that the JMS Broker is local and preferably inprocess so that there zero chance of a network blimp effecting the connection.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really a Spring question. What you're asking for is a mail sending mechanism that can queue sends on failure, with retries. You could, of course, create a bean with such capabilities, and wire it via Spring; it'd be very useful, I'd imagine, for some situations.

Comment: Thank you both Gareth and Joseph for your fast response.I think it will be usefull to persist messages in to DB or Queue as you suggest.but i thought there may be a way to this as stated in http://wheelersoftware.com/articles/spring-javamail.html

Comment: Only had a quick scan of that article but i couldn't see anything other than how to use the API to send mails...nothing about handling your use case..maybe I'm missing something